# Is it possible to bundle AAR files into an app bundle that is dynamically delivered at install time?

Tags: android, aar

I am trying to deliver an AR module only to devices of API level 24 but still support devices of API level 21. When I build the app bundle for an API lvl 24 device it runs fine. However, for the API level 21 devices it crashes at app launch with ClassNotFoundException as it is trying to load  a class in a library file that is for API 24 only.

It seems to me that the gradle import is defining the class definitions to load at start rather than anything done from the bundletool.

Has anyone had success with doing something similar? Is this not supported? Full stack trace below.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to get provider the.class.in.the.module.library: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "the.class.in.the.module.library" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.my.app==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.my.app==/lib/x86, /system/lib, /system/product/lib]]
    at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:6988)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:6528)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:6445)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:219)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1859)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "the.class.in.the.module.library" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.my.app==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.my.app==/lib/x86, /system/lib, /system/product/lib]]
    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:196)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
    at android.app.AppComponentFactory.instantiateProvider(AppComponentFactory.java:147)
    at androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory.instantiateProvider(CoreComponentFactory.java:60)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:6972)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:6528) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:6445) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:219) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1859) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out manifests are merged, which is fine for activities but not so much for providers...